# In MVC - Ajax call on page load is failing

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am giving ajax call on a page load. Its failing.

My ajax request is

```
  @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            '__RequestVerificationToken': token
        },
        url: "Home/Test",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        //data: JSON.stringify({ "ABC": "test" }),
        success: function (results) {
            //alert(url);
            alert("Success");
        },

        error: function (e) {
            alert(token);
            //alert("Fail");
        }
    });
});
```

The HomeController test  action method is

```
       [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Test()
    {
        return new JsonResult();
    }
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the controller, is it hitting the Test method?

Comment: What is the HTTP error?

Comment: @jwatts1980 Yes it is hitting Test method

Comment: @AllenKing No HTTP error on console

Comment: Can you please tell us what's being returned as the error?  You have `error: function (e)`, but you've told us nothing about `e`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the following changes:

1. Change the way you passing the parameter

**Example:**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        var data = { "ABC": "test" };

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Test")",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function (results) {
                //alert(url);
                alert("Success");
            },

            error: function (e) {
                alert("Fail");
            }
        });
    });
```

2. Change the Test method like this in the HomeController.

**Example:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test(string ABC)
{
    return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```